# How to fix, cannot find -lfaiss_c: No such file or directory

Tags: rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ld, rust-cargo, faiss

I'm building a Rust project using `cargo build`. But, I'm getting bellow error error as

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfaiss_c: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install `faiss` using `conda` as mentione [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/main/INSTALL.md). It's installed but somehow I'm still getting the same error.
Do I need to change any `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ?

Can anyone please suggest? I'm using `WSL` environment in Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.